# What is the correct type to use for this React form field hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a React hook (using typescript), but I can only get it to work if I use `any` for the type of the initial value.

I've tried combinations of `HTMLInputElement`, `React.FormEvent` (even `React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>`) as well as using `input type="text"` to try and restrict the input elements to `type: string.`

This is the hook:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export default function useField(initialValue: any) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleUpdate = useCallback(
    ({ currentTarget: { type, checked, value } }) => {
      setValue(type === "checkbox" ? checked : value);
    },
    []
  );

  return [value, handleUpdate];
}
```

And this is where it's being used:

```
import useField from "./hooks/useField";

const App = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useField("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useField("");
  const [age, setAge] = useField("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input value={firstName} name="firstName" onChange={setFirstName} />
        <input value={lastName} name="lastName" onChange={setLastName} />
        <input value={age} name="age" onChange={setAge} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It actually works as it is, using `initialValue: any` but I feel like the type should be more specific than that. If I do change it to a more specific type (e.g. string) then I get the following two errors.

```
(JSX attribute) React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.onChange?: ((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined
Type 'string | (({ currentTarget: { type, checked, value } }: any) => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1977, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
```

The second one is on the input onChange event:

```
(JSX attribute) React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>.onChange?: ((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined
Type 'string | (({ currentTarget: { type, checked, value } }: any) => void)' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1977, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'
```

Today is my first day of using Typescript, so this could potentially be something very obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the return type, TypeScript will infer it. I'll start with a simple example:

```
function strNum() {
  return [1, 'a'];
}
```

This returns the type `(string | number)[]`, that is, an array that can contain string or number elements.

`useField` returns an array of `string | (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void`. This means that any element of the array can be either of these types and they are not compatible with one another.

Instead, you can specify the return type as a tuple. This is an array of set length with specific element types.

```
useField(initialValue: string): [string, (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void] {
```